# Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable en prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop

estoy usando prestashop 1.7.6.5 y php 7.2 hace unos días me salió el siguiente error:

**Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/html/modules/blockwishlist/managewishlist.php on line 102**

Viene de un módulo que se utiliza para guardar la lista de deseos, este error se muestra cuando quiero ver los artículos que tengo guardados como favoritos, adjunto el código de ese archivo:

```
<?php
/* SSL Management */
$useSSL = true;

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../init.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/WishList.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/blockwishlist.php');
$context = Context::getContext();
if ($context->customer->isLogged())
{
    $action = Tools::getValue('action');
    $id_wishlist = (int)Tools::getValue('id_wishlist');
    $id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');
    $id_product_attribute = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product_attribute');
    $quantity = (int)Tools::getValue('quantity');
    $priority = Tools::getValue('priority');
    $wishlist = new WishList((int)($id_wishlist));
    $refresh = ((Tools::getValue('refresh') == 'true') ? 1 : 0);
    if (empty($id_wishlist) === false)
    {
        if (!strcmp($action, 'update'))
        {
            WishList::updateProduct($id_wishlist, $id_product, $id_product_attribute, $priority, $quantity);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!strcmp($action, 'delete'))
                WishList::removeProduct($id_wishlist, (int)$context->customer->id, $id_product, $id_product_attribute);

            $products = WishList::getProductByIdCustomer($id_wishlist, $context->customer->id, $context->language->id);
            $bought = WishList::getBoughtProduct($id_wishlist);

            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($products); ++$i)
            {
                $obj = new Product((int)($products[$i]['id_product']), false, $context->language->id);
                if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($obj))
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    if ($products[$i]['id_product_attribute'] != 0)
                    {
                        $combination_imgs = $obj->getCombinationImages($context->language->id);
                        if (isset($combination_imgs[$products[$i]['id_product_attribute']][0]))
                            $products[$i]['cover'] = $obj->id.'-'.$combination_imgs[$products[$i]['id_product_attribute']][0]['id_image'];
                        else
                        {
                            $cover = Product::getCover($obj->id);
                            $products[$i]['cover'] = $obj->id.'-'.$cover['id_image'];
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $images = $obj->getImages($context->language->id);
                        foreach ($images AS $k => $image)
                            if ($image['cover'])
                            {
                                $products[$i]['cover'] = $obj->id.'-'.$image['id_image'];
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    if (!isset($products[$i]['cover']))
                        $products[$i]['cover'] = $context->language->iso_code.'-default';
                }
                $products[$i]['bought'] = false;
                for ($j = 0, $k = 0; $j < sizeof($bought); ++$j)
                {
                    if ($bought[$j]['id_product'] == $products[$i]['id_product'] AND
                        $bought[$j]['id_product_attribute'] == $products[$i]['id_product_attribute'])
                        $products[$i]['bought'][$k++] = $bought[$j];
                }
            }

            $productBoughts = array();

            foreach ($products as $product)
                if (sizeof($product['bought']))
                    $productBoughts[] = $product;
            $context->smarty->assign(array(
                    'products' => $products,
                    'productsBoughts' => $productBoughts,
                    'id_wishlist' => $id_wishlist,
                    'refresh' => $refresh,
                    'token_wish' => $wishlist->token,
                    'wishlists' => WishList::getByIdCustomer($cookie->id_customer)
                ));

            // Instance of module class for translations
            $module = new BlockWishList();
            $context->smarty->assign('link',$context->link);
            if (Tools::file_exists_cache(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/blockwishlist/views/templates/front/managewishlist.tpl'))
                $context->smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/blockwishlist/views/templates/front/managewishlist.tpl');
            elseif (Tools::file_exists_cache(dirname(__FILE__).'/views/templates/front/managewishlist.tpl'))
                $context->smarty->display(dirname(__FILE__).'/views/templates/front/managewishlist.tpl');
            elseif (Tools::file_exists_cache(dirname(__FILE__).'/managewishlist.tpl'))
                $context->smarty->display(dirname(__FILE__).'/managewishlist.tpl');
            else
                echo $module->l('No template found', 'managewishlist');
        }
    }
}
```

La línea 102 empieza en esa parte:
[image: error]

Gracias por su atención c: y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola, Ana. ¿Qué modulo estás utilizando? ¿Te dejó de funcionar o fue recién instalándolo? ¿Actualizaste Prestashop o cambiaste de versión de PHP?

Comment: Este es uno de los cambios que se introdujeron en PHP7.2, ya solo se pueden contar cosas contables array, objetos o que implementen la interfaz countable, pero no cualquier otro tipo de datos como string, null, booleano... Seguramente `$product['bought']` contiene un tipo de dato que no es contable. Recordemos que `sizeof` es un alias de `count`

Comment: Hola @Adrian el módulo que estoy usando es Wishlist block, antes si funcionaba, apenas note esa advertencia, lo único que hice anteriormente fue actualizar un módulo que compre :/ pero no le he actualizado ni prestashop ni php

Comment: Hola @Xerif agradezco tu aportación ¿alguna sugerencia de cómo hacerlo en php 7.2? :(

Comment: @ana puedes comprobar en el mismo `if` primero si es un array que supongo es lo que quieres contar. Ejemplo: `if (is_array($product['bought']) and sizeof($product['bought']))`

Comment: En caso de que `$product['bought']` contenga un objeto puedes comprobar si implementa la interfaz `Countable` por ejemplo con `$product['bought'] instanceof Countable`

Comment: Gracias @Xerif me funcionó con lo que me comentaste de poner: `if (is_array($product['bought']) and sizeof($product['bought']))` de esa manera se desapareció el error, gracias. c: